# particle accelerator-Magnetic Fields

Tags: particle-physics

1)A magnetic field can never do work. Please Provide me with a simple answer as to why this is such. i assume that the magnetic force is always perpendicular to L by F=qvxB, esplaining why the cos(90)=0;

2) My research on Particle accelerators showed they rely upon magnetic fields. But increasing the kinetic energy of particles is work. How?

PS. I am a nerd; hit me up with nerdy answers but with logical sequence (do not assume I know anything! I will research though anything you ask me to). THANK YOU

Answer (score 2):

Of course magnetic fields can do work: hold a magnet near your refrigerator and let it snap into contact, or look up how a transformer or Betatron works.

But (most) particle accelerators use their magnets for steering particle, both to guide them in circles (so they can take a long path) and to focus them to keep them where they’re wanted. To accelerate them, adding velocity and energy, they use electric fields typically in the form of radio-frequency voltages.

Comment: This. The words left out (or forgotten) by most people are "A magnetic field does no work **on free particles**". or similar qualification.

Answer (score 1):

> A magnetic field can never do work. Please Provide me with a simple answer as to why this is such. i assume that the magnetic force is always perpendicular to L by F=qvxB, esplaining why the cos(90)=0;

Yes, it has to do with the cross product, BUT the statement is not correct:

> [Because the magnetic force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_field) is always perpendicular to the motion, the magnetic field can do no work on an *isolated* charge. *It can only do work indirectly, via the electric field generated by a changing magnetic field*.

Italics mine. In the example given by Bob in his answer, the magnetic field is changing as you are nearing the fridge, and gets attracted to the bound charges and induce magnetic dipoles of the door.

> My research on Particle accelerators showed they rely upon magnetic fields. But increasing the kinetic energy of particles is work. How?

By changing magnetic fields in the electromagnets.

It is an observation and mathematically modeled that changing electric fields generate magnetic fields and vice verso. When this happens together , you get [electromagnetic radiation,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_radiation) of which light is a part.